# Navigating to section/fragment (href=page#section) on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add in my footer.php a `#section` to the contact form and it works great on PC browsers but Android web development is making me go nuts.

How can I add a section link to `page_2#form` from `page_1`?

I have tried

`<a name=form> ... <a href=page_2#form>`

and

`<div id=form name=form> ... <a href=page_2#form>`

but Android browsers don't like it.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Here! Have a polyfill:

```
(function checkHashFragForSection () {
  document.addEventListener('load', fragExtractor)
  addEventListener('hashchange', fragExtractor)

  function fragExtractor () {
    var split = location.href.split('#')
    if(split[1] && split[1].length > 0) scrollToSection(split[1])
  }

  function scrollToSection (name) {
    var newPos = getYOffset(getElement(name))
    if(newPos) scrollTo(newPos)
  }

  function getElement (name) {
    return document.getElementById(name)
  }

  function getYOffset(elem) {
    var offset = 0
    if(!elem) return false
    while (elem && (offset += elem.offsetTop)) elem = elem.offsetParent
    return offset
  }
})()
```